# js does not repeat html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[image]

I'm trying to customize the code that I found. If I use `ul` then `li` tags not missing but if I trying in select use option work html tags only with first option, others showing in console but not with option tags.. Please help me..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#group").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "http://localhost/egama/gama/groups/duties/duties_by_group_api/" + $("#group").val(),
      cache: false,
      data: 'search=' + $("#group").val(),
      success: function(response) {
        $('#finalResultDuty').html("");
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        if (obj.length > 0) {
          try {
            var items = [];
            $.each(obj, function(i, val) {
              items.push(innerHTML = "<option>" + val.title + "</option>");
            });
            $('#finalResultDuty').append.apply($('#finalResultDuty'), items);
          } catch (e) {
            alert('Error');
          }
        } else {
          $('#finalResultDuty').html($('<option/>').innerHTML = "<option value=''>Pareigos neaktyvios arba nesukurtos</option>");
        }

      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="finalResultDuty" name="duty"></select>
```

Comment: Your English is really hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working, but a simple solution is to use a string rather than an array.

```
var items = '';
$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
  items += "<option>" + val.title + "</option>";
});
$('#finalResultDuty').html(items);
```